# Como agregar y eliminar datos de un array segun el valor con splice

Tags: jquery

hola nececito ayuda con una aplicaccion en la cual tengo 5 **checkboxes** podrian ser mas asta 100 pero estoy haciendo el ejemplo solo con 5.

pues bien, la cosa es que al ejelir opciones de transporte en realidad se estan clickeando chechboxes que a la vez se ira guardo el valor seleccionado en un array con `push`, pero tambien nececito que si se deselecciona ese **checkbox** me saque espesificamente ese mismo valor deseleccionado, entiendo que con `splice` es la opcion correpta para ello pero al hacerlo con **splice** me borra todo lo que habia guardado en el array, pero solo nececito que me borre el checkbox **deseleccionado** segun lo que vaya eligiendo.

todo esto es con el fin de cambiar el color de unos **divs** cuando el usuario haya elegido las opciones de transporte preferidas, entonces cuando  haga click en un boton **verificar** quiero que el color de los divs cambie segun las opciones elegidas por el usurio.

los **divs** al igual que los checkboxes son 5 con su nombre correspondientes aqui les dejo lo que estoy intentando cualquier ayuda o tips se los agradeceria.

```js
$(function(){

var data=[];//

$("ul li input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){

      var valor=$(this).val()

      if($(this).is(":checked")){

        data.push(valor);
         
      }else{

       data.splice($(this).valor);
       

      }

})

 // cambiar color de los divs correspondinte al clikear verificar //  

  $("#Verificar").click(function(){

      console.log(data)
  //aqui cambiar el color de los divs segun los checkboxes
  //elegidos caundo el usuario haga click en verificar
  //aqui leeriamos el array data para dicho objetivo    
  
  })
});
```

```css
ul{
  position:relative;
 width:100%;
}
ul li{
 position:relative;
 list-style:none;
 padding:5px;
 border-bottom:solid 1px lightgrey;
 width:100%;
}

ul li:focus{
color:red;
background:red;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    
   position:absolute; 
   display:block;
   right:0;
   width:100%;
 
   cursor:pointer;

}

#transport{

   padding:10px;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
}
#transport div{
  background:lightgrey;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="combo" multiple>
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="car" value="car" multiple/>car</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="bike" value="bike" multiple />bike</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="truck" value="truck" multiple />truck</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="plane" value="plane" multiple />plane</li>

  <li><input type="checkbox" id="motorBike" value="motorbike" multiple/>motor bike</li>
</ul>
</div>

<button id="Verificar">Verificar</button>


<div id="transport">
    <div id="car-c"  data-transport="car" class="transport">CAR</div>
    <div id="bike-c"  data-transport="bike" class="transport">BIKE</div>
    <div id="truck-c"  data-transport="truck" class="transport"> TRUCK</div>
    <div id="plane-c"  data-transport="plane" class="transport">PLANE</div>
    <div id="motorBike-c"  data-transport="motorBike" class="transport">MOTOR BIKE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: y como funciona splice? te pregunto porque antes de usar algo deberías aprender como usarlo -> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice

Comment: se mas o menos como funciona por eso vengo aqui a aclarar dudas gracias

Comment: `data.splice($(this).valor,1);`

Comment: te dejé un link que explica bastante bien como funciona y con varios ejemplos, no tomes el camino corto para resolver problemas lee las definiciones de los métodos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiqué un poco tu **js**, cambie el **click** por **change** porque creo que es mejor ya que en realidad ellos cambian de estado y es mejor manejarlos por el **change** y solo de debe de ejecutar cuando detecte un cambio en su estado; tambien use el la función `indexOf` y le coloco el valor que no ha sido chequeado para que me retorne su indice en el **array** y posteriormente removerlo con el `splice`, espero te sirva:

```js
$(function(){

var data=[];//

$("ul li input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
      
      var valor = $(this).val();
      
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
        data.push(valor);         
      }else{
        var index = data.indexOf(valor);
        data.splice(index, 1);
      }

})

  $("#Verificar").click(function(){

      console.log(data)
  //aqui cambiar el color de los divs segun los checkboxes
  //elegidos caundo el usuario haga click en verificar
  //aqui leeriamos el array data para dicho objetivo    
  
  })
});
```

```css
ul{
  position:relative;
 width:100%;
}
ul li{
 position:relative;
 list-style:none;
 padding:5px;
 border-bottom:solid 1px lightgrey;
 width:100%;
}

ul li:focus{
color:red;
background:red;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    
   position:absolute; 
   display:block;
   right:0;
   width:100%;
 
   cursor:pointer;

}

#transport{

   padding:10px;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
}
#transport div{
  background:lightgrey;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="combo" multiple>
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="car" value="car" multiple/>car</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="bike" value="bike" multiple />bike</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="truck" value="truck" multiple />truck</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="plane" value="plane" multiple />plane</li>

  <li><input type="checkbox" id="motorBike" value="motorbike" multiple/>motor bike</li>
</ul>
</div>

<button id="Verificar">Verificar</button>


<div id="transport">
    <div id="car-c"  data-transport="car" class="transport">CAR</div>
    <div id="bike-c"  data-transport="bike" class="transport">BIKE</div>
    <div id="truck-c"  data-transport="truck" class="transport"> TRUCK</div>
    <div id="plane-c"  data-transport="plane" class="transport">PLANE</div>
    <div id="motorBike-c"  data-transport="motorBike" class="transport">MOTOR BIKE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: habia estado practicando y consegui lo mismo que esta respuesta gracias a sus ideas pude hacerlo completa la funcion que andaba buscando en breve les muestro como lo resorvi

Comment: Que bueno que pudiste solventar

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes cambiar en el splice un detallito,
**Modificar** esto:

```
data.splice($(this).valor);
```

**Por**:

```
var index = data.indexOf(valor);
data.splice(index, 1);
```

Lo que hace el codigo de arriba es buscar elemento en el arreglo y eliminarlo.

Comment: el codigo anterior si funciono

Comment: y este no te funciono????

Comment: noup del todo amigo

Comment: dame volvertelo a poner

Comment: Revisa a ver y me dices :)

Answer (score 0):

asi quedo el codigo final para conseguir lo que queria

```js
$(function(){
 




var data=[];//

$("ul li input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){

      var valor=$(this).val()

      if($(this).is(":checked")){

        data.push(valor);
         
      }else{

       var index=data.indexOf(valor)

       data.splice(index,1);
       

      }

})

 // cambiar color de los divs correspondinte al clikear verificar //  

  $("#Verificar").click(function(){
  
    var i=0;

        for(i; i < data.length; i++){

          $("#"+data[i]+"-c").fadeIn().css({"background":"red","border-radius":"50%","width":"25px","height":"25px",})
       console.log(data)
    }
  
  })
});
```

```css
ul{
  position:relative;
 width:100%;
}
ul li{
 position:relative;
 list-style:none;
 padding:5px;
 border-bottom:solid 1px lightgrey;
 width:100%;
}

ul li:focus{
color:red;
background:red;
}
ul li:hover{
color:red;
background:#F5F5F5;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    
   position:absolute; 
   display:block;
   right:0;
   width:100%;
   height:30px;
   cursor:pointer;

}

#transport{
   position:relative;
   padding:10px;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
}
#transport div{
  background:lightgrey;
  padding:10px;
}
#transport div i{
  display:none;
  padding:5px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-12px;
margin-left:-10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="combo" multiple>
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="car" value="car" multiple/>car</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="bike" value="bike" multiple />bike</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="truck" value="truck" multiple />truck</li>

 <li><input type="checkbox" id="plane" value="plane" multiple />plane</li>

  <li><input type="checkbox" id="motorBike" value="motorBike" multiple/>motor bike</li>
</ul>
</div>

<button id="Verificar">Verificar</button>


<div id="transport">
    <div  data-transport="car" class="transport">
     <i id="car-c"></i>
     

CAR</div>
    <div   data-transport="bike" class="transport">
 <i id="bike-c"></i>
BIKE</div>
    <div   data-transport="truck" class="transport"> 
<i id="truck-c"></i>
TRUCK</div>
    <div   data-transport="plane" class="transport">
<i id="plane-c"></i>
PLANE</div>
    <div   data-transport="motorBike" class="transport">

<i id="motorBike-c"></i>
MOTOR BIKE</div>
</div>
```